# TableView pushed down after view change

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm kind of new with ios development with swift 4, so I'm testing some functionalities.
I have a tableview inside a normal `UIViewController`: [image: tableviewlayout]

The space left blank is intentionally, as I have some custom tabs.

When I show a detail from a table cell element, and then press back button, the table view gets pushed down (and up). Please see [this](http://gph.is/2EJJCkv) where I show the problem.

The iphone is a SE with ios10. **In simulations with iOS11, this does not happen.** Developing in MacOS Sierra 10.12.6 with xCode 9.2.

Any clue on how to fix this?

EDIT:

Using the view debugger, I got this:
[image: viewdebugger]

The selected area is a `UITableWrapperView` element. Behind it, is the `UITableView`, which preserve its constrains.

Comment: its seems to be a constraint issue for me

Comment: just as an experiment, try to change the `UITableView` style to `.plain` (or `.grouped` if you have plain alread).. I remember that a year ago I had something similar which happened with one of those styles and with other it worked as expected..

Comment: @MilanNosáľ with grouped, appears a grey space between the top tabs. But, when I go to the details page, the table gets pushed down anyways.

Answer (score 1):

set

```
self.tableView.bounces = false
```

Or put this in viewDidAppear

```
 let offset = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y:0)
 self.tableView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: false)
```

Comment: push down happens automatically ?

Comment: Yes, the push down happens automatically. I just tested your edit. It does returns the tableview to its original position, but as I scroll it, it gets pushed down again.

Comment: save the last content offset X when you perform the segue and restore it again

Answer (score 0):

It can happen because of SafeArea... Check you constraint which connects tableView top with navigation bar.

You can also try placing blank UIView between Navigation bar and tableView. Your custom tabs should be in this view. So tableView will be connected with the nearest view (which you have just added) and should not bounce.

Comment: I tried this, but as I updated the OP, the table view is in its place. The things moving are the cells.

Comment: @CamiloR did you try to set `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `false`? This property was deprecated in iOS 11, but in iOS 10 and lower it could cause undesirable content indentation. Since you have this strange behavior on iOS 10 only this worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

Thats a really weird behavior. I recommend you to use the [Xcode view debugger](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015022-CH9-SW2). You would be able to examine dimensions and constraints values by using size inspector.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll edit the OP so everyone can see the debug. The tableview is in its place, but somecalled ```UITableWrapperView``` is the one pushed down.

Answer (score 0):

The code where you set up your tableview, try implementing it in the method viewDidLayoutSubviews(in case you are doing it in viewDidLoad).

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    //mention your tableview setup code here
}
```

A similar thing happened to me, and this method came quite handy. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for iOS 11.0

```
tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```